# EF6.1 Unique contraints over multiple columns

Tags: entity-framework

Consider the following class

```
public class Foo
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public virtual User User { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [MaxLength(20)]
  public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

I need to combine User and Token into a unique constraint in the table. I thought this would be possible using the attribute [Index(IsUnique=true)]

I was testing this by first applying the attribute only to the Token property and then only to the User property. On the Token property I got the expected exception when adding duplicate records however on the User property I did not.

The user property is a foreign key (in this case an in) into the user table but this attribute wasn't enforcing uniqueness. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the answer through trial and error:

I needed to explicitly declare the foreign key for User rather than letting EF work it out. Then I can add the Index attribute to the foreign key property.

So rather than trying to do this:

```
  [Required]
  [Index("UserToken", 1, IsUnique = true)]
  public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

I had to do this:

```
  [Required]
  [ForeignKey("UserId")]
  public virtual User User { get; set; }

  [Index("UserToken", 1, IsUnique = true)]
  public int UserId { get; set; }
```